# property similar to SPQuery listitemcollectionposition for spsitedataquery

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, visual-studio, site-collection, spsitedataquery

I am using SPSiteDataQuery to get all matched items from all lists in site collection.
Results set is really large, so I want to limit the results to 1000 or 10K, process these items and then iterate through remaining matched items. I am looking for somewhat similar property to ListItemCollectionPosition in SPQuery, that will allow to loop through the 
result-set till all items are processed.

Or is there any way in which I dont have to get all result-sets at once, and then get 10K results and process them in loop till all matched items are done processing. I really dont want to get 1 million results at once.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but SPSiteDataQuery only supports limiting the number of results not paging to the next set.

If you're using 2010 Server you can use [ContentIterator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.utilities.contentiterator.aspx)

But if you're using Foundation then your only option is to put some hidden column into all the lists which you can use to break the items into sets.

Comment: That's a dirty workaround but sadly true. +1